# Retriving JSON from Flask endpoint

Tags: python, json, d3.js, flask, gist

I'm using a D3 script to display [pie charts](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235) on a Flask-built site, and using JSON to serve the data to those pie charts. However, I'm getting an error message from my D3-powered site when I open it:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

My D3-powered .js file contains this line which retrieves the JSON for the pie charts:

```
var json_data = "http://the.site/dashboard-data"
```

My Python code in the Flask-powered "app.py" file looks like this (specifically for the endpoint containing my JSON):

```
@app.route('/dashboard-data')
def display_dashboard_data():
    parent_path = '\\'.join(os.path.realpath(__file__).split('\\')[:-1])
    file_path = os.path.join(parent_path, 'static\\js\\default_data.json')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file_data:
        json_data = json.load(file_data)
    return render_template('dashboard_data.html', data=json_data)
```

The JSON appears without a problem, but my assumption is that the aforementioned site-error is caused by the presence of single-quotes instead of double-quotes. Also, the issue could also be that the JSON is stored within HTML tags. Here's what the site containing the JSON looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json" charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        {&#39;data&#39;: [{&#39;id&#39;: [...the rest of the JSON is found here.]
    </body>
</html>
```

So the question is this: what's the best way to serve up this JSON to my D3 page?

Note: I developed the D3 code using a Github Gist, which had a very convenient "Raw" option when viewing the content in my JSON file. That raw endpoint would have a .json extension in it (similar to [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/planetoftheweb/98f35786733c8cccf81e/raw/f3dad774ed1fe20b36011b1261bb392ee759b867/data.json)) which my application does not have. Is there a way to mimic that "Raw" endpoint in my own application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider creating a separate endpoint that returns JSON response.

```
@app.route('/artists')
def artists():
    parent_path = '\\'.join(os.path.realpath(__file__).split('\\')[:-1])
    file_path = os.path.join(parent_path, 'static\\js\\default_data.json')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file_data:
        json_data = json.load(file_data)
    return jsonify(json_data)
```

This way, having your client side javascript code make a request to this endpoint to retrieve the data in JSON will be without hassle.